# passing this to a function changes all clicked elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Shapes are added to a canvas and a click function is assigned to each item. On click an edit window shows up that enables the user to edit the shapes

```
function place(id, top, leftpx, width, height, color) {
  var dropped;

  dropped.attr('s_id', id)
    .appendTo('.xy')
    .data({
      'posleft': leftpx,
      'postop': top,
      'width': width,
      'height': height,
      'color': color
    })
    .css({
      top: top + "px",
      left: leftpx + "px",
      position: "absolute",
      width: width,
      height: height
    });

  dropped.resizable({
    containment: '.xyz',
    handles: 'all',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).data('width', ui.size.width);
      $(this).data('height', ui.size.height);
    }
  });

  dropped.click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("shelf_id"); // gives the correct id
    edit($(this));
  });
```

When I click one item, it changes the color correctly, but as soon as I click a second one, it also changes the color of the item that was clicked before. Corresponding function is the following:

```
function edit(item) {
  //edit window shows up

  $("#editDataForm").submit(function(e) {

    var id_color = $("#colorSelect option:selected").val();

    if (item.data('color') != id_color) {
      switch (id_color) {
        case '1':
          item.css("background-color", "yellowgreen");
          item.data('color', id_color);
          break;
        case '2':
          item.css("background-color", "indianred");
          item.data('color', id_color);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Could someone please give me a hint where my mistake in reasoning is. I just cant crack it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `edit(item)` you add an additional `submit()` handler to the form. When you submit the form, all those handler functions run, and they each change the color of the item that was clicked on when you called `edit`.

If you only want to affect the last one, you need to remove the previous event handler. You can do this with the `.off()` method.

```
function edit(item) {
  //edit window shows up

  $("#editDataForm").off("submit").submit(function(e) {

    var id_color = $("#colorSelect option:selected").val();

    if (item.data('color') != id_color) {
      switch (id_color) {
        case '1':
          item.css("background-color", "yellowgreen");
          item.data('color', id_color);
          break;
        case '2':
          item.css("background-color", "indianred");
          item.data('color', id_color);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Comment: Or: `$("#editDataForm").one('submit', function(e){...});`

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't think that will do it. Each call to `.one()` will add a new handler that runs once and removes itself. But if you call `edit()` multiple times before submitting, each of them will still run.